# Stuck on integrated intel HD 630 graphics card, cannot use dedicated nvidia 940mx graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a thinkpad T470p with a nvidia 940mx. The laptop used to use the dedicated card back when I first installed ubuntu on it right after 20.04 came out, I emulated a few ps2 games on it. But for the last few months, I suspect since the kernel was updated to 5.8 I am stuck using the integrated intel card.

I have updated my nvidia driver to the latest GM108M-driver-465 and have used prime-select to switch to the nvidia card, which it says it is using. But under the gnome settings about page it says that I am using the integrated intel card (Mesa Intel HD graphics 630).

When I run `nvidia-smi -l 1` the output is

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI, not only install drivers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks man, this was the solution

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some issues with my MX250 drivers a few weeks ago and I received the same message on running nvidia-smi. What I did was purge the current nvidia drivers and then install the nvidia-driver-465 using the "Aditional drivers" tab in Software & Updates. After a quick restart I got the correct information on running nvidia-smi.

```
parth@parth-laptop:~$ nvidia-smi 
Wed Jun 16 01:25:22 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.27       Driver Version: 465.27       CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      4MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A   1037803      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately unsuccessful, I apt-get purged all the nvidia drivers and reinstalled the latest 465 but still the same error message when trying to run nvidia-smi

Comment: Thanks for your help, the solution was to disable UEFI secure boot

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution for visibility, the solution was from @ChanganAuto. The solution was to disable UEFI secure boot in my bios